# Can't load jQuery in WordPress <head>

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Wordpress no matter how I try to include jQuery it always loads it together with the bottom scripts, never in head. What could be the cause? I've also removed all the jquery includes from functions.php (both child and parent theme), now the jQuery should not load at all, but it still does.

Is it possible that some cache causes it? I've cleared cache in wp-content/cache already.

How could I investigate it? I have no clue, I guess only that it is some plugin that includes jquery, but I have "tens" of plugins, turning them on and then off would be a bit hassle.

Comment: Why do you want to load Jquery in the `<head>` ?

Comment: wp_enquqe_scripts() sticks them in the wp_footer() by default so they don't block the page load.  This is best practice AFAIk.  If load order is an issue, you can manualy set the order via the priority.  jQuery is part of WP Core.

Comment: The reason I need it there is that one of the plugins inserts command jQuery()...  inside html, before script is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I forget the version where this started, but jQuery is part of WordPress. You can delete the enqueue scripts from `functions.php`, but jQuery is still going to be there.

You'll have to deregister jQuery first, and then you can call a different version of jQuery or some other library.

```
// include custom jQuery
function deregister_jquery_and_add_something_else() {

    // If you only want to disable jQuery, just use this line
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    // If you want to use a different version or another script, enqueue it here
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'deregister_jquery_and_add_something_else');
```

Although, as previous commenters have noted you'll want to be wary of doing that. While you CAN load scripts in the head, it is render-blocking and will affect performance of your site when it comes to page load speed.

If you must load scripts in the `<head>` for some reason, make sure you're using `defer` or `async`.

Comment: the last parameter of `wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false );` is `$in_footer` so if you set it to `true` the script will be loaded in the footer...

Comment: I need jQuery to be loaded in head because some plugin inserts js command "jQuery()..." inside html, before footer. I know it should not do it, but wordpress is such quality system. Additionally I don't want to include any external jquery, I'd like to use the one that Wordpress already have. At third, your function still puts the script in the footer...

Comment: If you have a plugin that's forcing jQuery in the `<head>`, it might be a good idea to seek alternatives that perform the same functionality. And yes, if you use the entire function above it adds jQuery 3.3.1. The code snippet has comments that explain what each line does - try omitting `wp_enqueue_script` after the `wp_deregister_script` line.